# Filter Array results before showing in Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, restkit

**I need to filter the array I'm using so it doesn't show all of the results (want to only show first 20 of 100 `leafs`) in my `UITableView`.**

Can't figure out how to do it.  Let me know if you would like more code posted!

*(I'm using RestKit, pulling from an API, and already have the Object Mapping working fine)*

ViewController.m

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *springs;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *leafs;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
       [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] 
       loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/ss/?apikey=xx" 
       usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
            loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){

                  springs = objects;

// @cream-corn this is the for statement you suggested, but I can't finish it
        for (Sport *sport in objects){
                for (Leaf *leaf in spring.leafs){
                    if (leaf.abbreviation isEqualToString:@"ap"){
// This is where I can't figure out what to put
                        [];
                    }
                }
            }


              [_tableView reloadData];


          // @cream-corn this is where I log that I'm getting correct data
            for (Spring *sppring in objects){
             NSLog(@"%@", spring.name);
            for (Leaf *leaf in spring.leafs){
              NSLog(@"     %@ %@", leaf.name, leaf.abbreviation);
                 }
            }


            };

            [loader.mappingProvider  
        setMapping:[Spring mapping] 
        forKeyPath:@"springs"];
            loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){

            };
        }];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:section];
        return spring.leafs.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];  // 13 objects
        Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // 30 objects

        cell.textLabel.text = leaf.shortName;
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay, so. do you want to filter the array specifically? i.e.: remove objects that meet a certain condition? **OR** just display the first 20 in the table view?

If the former is correct **(assuming that this array is mutable)** you can do something like this: **(this is a form of psudeocode this code won't copy/paste)**

```
for(id obj in [myMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if(obj does not meet condition) {

        [myMutableArray remove:obj]

    }
}
```

`reverseObjectEnumerator` is the most important piece of this loop, without it; it will throw an exception because you are mutating whilst enumerating.

If the latter is correct you can do this:

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection (NSInteger)section
{
    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:section];
    return MIN(spring.leafs.count, 20);
}
```

the line `return MIN(spring.leafs.count,20);` just returns the smaller number, either `spring.leafs.count` or `20`

Comment: If I do the latter, it crashes on the `Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` line inside `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`, with the error `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'` in the console... any ideas on why?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I do the former, is that code going at the end of my `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: no, that code should be when you get the response, inside `[loadObjectsAtResourcePath:usingBlock:]` before you reload the data.

Comment: Also, Any idea on the latter solution that I had crash on me?

Comment: Oh wow, i made a (big) mistake, try using MIN(x,y) instead of MAX. ill edit the  answer.

Comment: hi @Reez have you ever try `NSPredicate` for filtering array?

Comment: @ClaricPWI I've heard of it and looked at it before, but never actually used it.  I couldn't quite figure out how to get it to work for this specifically, but if you have something you think will work I definitely would appreciate that!

Comment: @cream-corn I did exactly what you put for the min, and I think I understand why that would work, but it still listed all of the results and didn't limit to 20.  I can't figure out why that would be?  Because I do want to limit the results to only 20.

Comment: @cream-corn I edited my code above in my `viewDidLoad` to show you the `for` statement I'm currently using that just `NSLog`s that I'm getting the correct data.  I'm assuming the `for` statement you're suggesting, and that I already have, are almost exactly what I need to have to filter this array.  But I can't figure out how to add the `for` statement that your suggesting.  Can you help me out?  I basically need it to say "if leaf not equal to apex or vein then don't show in leaf tableview".  What I've tried so far hasn't worked.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @cream-corn I edited my `viewDidLoad` to also add my best shot at the `for` statement you suggested.  I'm so close, but can you help me finish that out?